# rescue inside an each_line code block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm completely "fresh" to Ruby and coming from a .NET background.

I'm trying to create a really simple rake task to import file with json objects into my database.
My IDE is raising an error when I'm trying to rescue inside the code block of each_line

```
File.open('etc/metrics_json.log').each_line do |line|
  metric_hash = JSON.parse(line)
  Metric.create(metric_hash)
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    puts e.message
end
```

the error is "syntax error, unexpected keyword_rescue, expecting keyword_end"

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please don't completely change the question after it has already been answered. You'll make every answer useless, and every answerer look like an idiot. Edits are for improvements, not for asking a new question. Asking a new question is for asking a new question. (That being said: both this question and the new one will probably be closed as being "a simple typographical error that is unlikely to be of help for future readers".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use it like

```
File.open('etc/metrics_json.log').each_line do |line|
  begin
    metric_hash = JSON.parse(line)
    Metric.create(metric_hash)
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    puts e.message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use method `def` as begin. For eg

```
def example_method
 ....
rescue
 ....
end
```

if not, you need to use `begin end`.

```
  begin
    metric_hash = JSON.parse(line)
    Metric.create(metric_hash)
  rescue RuntimeError => e
    puts e.message
  end
```